# jquery add/delete valid email address

Tags: jquery, validation

I am trying validate an email address and add that to a multi select box. For validating the email address i am using this example from jquery site. How can add i valid email address to the select box.?

```
$("#myform").validate({
    rules: {
    field: {
        required: true,
         email: true
}
```

}
})

```
  <SELECT id="emailRecipients" multiple size=12 name=emailRecipients> 
    <OPTION value=avendor@gmail.com>avendor@gmail.com</OPTION>
    <OPTION value=janedoe@yahoo.com>janedoe@yahoo.com</OPTION> 
  </SELECT>

 <INPUT class="secbtn" value="Add" type="button" id="addButton">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First obtain the validated email, then:

```
$('#addButton').click(function(){
  $('#emailRecipients').append('<OPTION value=' + email + '>' + email + '</OPTION>');
});
```

This will append the new option with the new email to the select once the add button is clicked.

Comment: I also did something like this.
 $(select).append("<optionvalue="+$(this).attr('id')+">"+$(this).attr('name')+"</option>");

Comment: @ tiagoboldt I have implemented this, both add and delete are working on FF, but not working on IE. When am adding valid email address width of the select box is decreasing for some strange reason and also the validation method is also nt working.  

Can you please help me on how do i fix this..?
[Sample Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pixelfx/cyTRf/)

Comment: Couple of comments: Use a single $(document).ready(). It's easier to maintain and read. Also, try not to have many levels of functions. Create the functions separately and then use them as parameters instead of defining them in place. I usually create a function setup(){..} with all initializations and then just do $(document).ready(setup); ||| also, you're not checking if the email is valid on each email: try adding the isValidEmail validation to the addButton click event so that the validation is done each time the user tries to add a new email. hope it helps, good luck

Comment: Thanks tiagoboldt. But i am not able understand why the width of select box is decreasing in IE, when am trying to add email addresses continuously?

Answer (score 1):

After you have checked if the email is valid. You can

```
var options = $('#emailRecipients').attr('options');
options[options.length] = new Option(emailAdd, emailAdd, true, true);
```

Where `emailAdd` is the validated email address